# Equivalent Spanish word for "well- tried" and "fantastic"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, español-neutral

What could be the equivalent Spanish word for "well- tried" and "fantastic"?

For example, on:

> - The teacher motivated him saying "well-tried" since he got most of the questions wrong.
>
> - Fantastic, you have done it.

Comment: Simply "casi" is arguably motivational coupled with the right tone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Well-tried**

At first I thought about translating it as *buen intento*, but for me this expression means that you missed the right answer for only a little bit, or that you made a good argumentation despite not having guessed the right answer. In this context, IMHO the translation should be ***al menos lo has intentado*** (mostly used in Spain) or ***al menos lo intentaste*** (in almost every country in Spanish-speaking America). This sentence translates back into English as "well... you tried" or "at least you tried".

**Fantastic**

The direct translation is ***[fantástico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HbMYFRw)***:

> 4. adj. coloq. Magnífico, excelente.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This _well-tried_ sounds a bit condescending, but in fact I guess it is the goal when saying this. I would also use _buen intento_.